# python discord.py embed text with buttons

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm doing a text quest in a discord bot, who knows how to make several buttons to go to different embed texts with a return function. I only know how to make embed text, but I don't understand about buttons and return function.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This site works best for specific problems in your code. It's not a replacement for tutorials and text books. Please check the discord python documentation and try some code. If you get stuck with that code, ask again, providing a [mcve]. See [ask].

Comment: Here's an [example of buttons](https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord/blob/master/examples/views/confirm.py) in nextcord and [simple tutorial to understand `return`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/). Discord.py is a complicated library and it's not suitable for begineer.

Answer (score 0):

Examples related to views can be found [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples/views/).